# Liferay: wrong .jsp after action phase and not the right values

Tags: java, jsp, parameters, liferay, portlet

I have big trouble how to use action and rendering phase properly in Liferay.

I am showing different links out of a list of objects using a for-loop.
Now I want to click on one of the link and go to the next .jsp. The content of the new .jsp depends on an id connected to object/link.

How do I do that?

My code looks like this so far:

ePfad.jsp

```
<% EpfadUtil all = new EpfadUtil();
List pfade = all.getEpfad();
for(int i = 0; i < pfade.size(); i++){
    Epfad pfad = (Epfad) pfade.get(i);
    //actionResponse.setRenderParameter("id", String.valueOf(pfad.getEpfadId()));
%>
<a href = "<portlet:actionURL name="showById"><portlet:param name="mvcPath" value="/html/wbm/user/ePfadAnmelden.jsp?id=<%=pfad.getEPfadId() %>" /> </portlet:actionURL>"> <%=pfad.getTitle().getName()%> </a>
<% } %>
```

WBM_Portlet.java

```
public class WBM_Portlet extends MVCPortlet {
    public void showById(ActionRequest actionRequest, ActionResponse actionResponse) throws IOException, PortletException {
        PortletPreferences prefs = actionRequest.getPreferences();
        String id = actionRequest.getParameter("id");

        if(id != null) {
            prefs.setValue("id", id);
            prefs.store();
        }
    }
//[...]
}
```

My code will not redirect to the right jsp and the id is also not correct.

Thank you and best regards.

Solution:

ePfad.jsp

```
<portlet:renderURL var="showByIdRenderURL">
    <portlet:param name="mvcPath" value="/html/wbm/user/ePfadAnmelden.jsp" />
    <portlet:param name="id" value="<%=String.valueOf(pfad.getEPfadId()) %>" />
</portlet:renderURL>

<a href="<%=showByIdRenderURL%>"><%=pfad.getTitle().getName() %></a>
```

WBM_Portlet.java

```
public void showById(RenderRequest request,
        RenderResponse response) throws IOException, PortletException
        {
            PortletPreferences prefs = request.getPreferences();
            String id = request.getParameter("id");

            if(id != null)
            {
                prefs.setValue("id", id);
                prefs.store();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Action URL's are for submitting forms via POST only. You should be using render URLs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to show another JSP then you should use the render phase and not action phase. So here is how you can use the renderURL:

```
<portlet:renderURL var="showByIdRenderURL">
    <portlet:param name="mvcPath" value="/html/wbm/user/ePfadAnmelden.jsp %>" />
    <portlet:param name="id" value="<%= String.valueOf(pfad.getEPfadId()) %>" />
</portlet:renderURL>

<a href="<%= showByIdRenderURL %>"><%=pfad.getTitle().getName()%></a>
```

And in `render` method or `doView` method you can write your logic to store the preference from the parameter `id` (please note how the `id` in the above URL is set as a parameter, the way you did it is incorrect)

If you want to still use action phase (not recommended for such things, it is better suited for form-posts) then you can do the following:

```
<portlet:actionURL name="showById" var="showByIdActionURL">
    <portlet:param name="mvcPath" value="/html/wbm/user/ePfadAnmelden.jsp %>" />
    <portlet:param name="id" value="<%= String.valueOf(pfad.getEPfadId()) %>" />
</portlet:actionURL>

<a href="<%= showByIdActionURL %>"><%=pfad.getTitle().getName()%></a>
```

In your action method:

```
public void showById(ActionRequest actionRequest, ActionResponse actionResponse) throws IOException, PortletException {
    PortletPreferences prefs = actionRequest.getPreferences();
    String id = actionRequest.getParameter("id");

    if(id != null) {
        prefs.setValue("id", id);
        prefs.store();
    }

   String mvcPath = actionRequest.getParameter("mvcPath");

   // this would tell the render method to show the required JSP
   actionResponse.setRenderParameter("mvcPath", mvcPath); 
}
```

Hope this answers the question.

But if you really want to develop something substantial and learn i would strongly suggest you go through some good tutorials which explains the concepts of the different phases of portlet life-cycle or some good books like `Portlets in Action` or `Liferay in Action`, even by going through the stackwiki links - [liferay](/questions/tagged/liferay) and [portlet](/questions/tagged/portlet) would give you a better idea.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I cannot really find any good tutorials for my problem and with your code i get a cryptic string with an Liferay link right before the actual link and it says "not found".

I added the ne Code to my post.

I do not really want to get far into Liferay, i just need it for one project for my univerity class. I just need to learn how to solve my actual problem and do Post-Formulars. (At the moment I do not think I will need anymore)